# Is there a way to automatically remove trailing whitespace when saving with gedit?

Tags: gedit, plugin

Is there a plugin of some sorts that gets rid of trailing spaces and tabs in every line when saving a file edited with gedit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, [`gedit-whitespace-remover`](https://github.com/dinkel/gedit-whitespace-remover/). It hasn’t been updated in a while but still works with GNOME 3.34.

Answer (score 0):

Do a regex find and replace:

```
Find: [^\S\n]*\n

Replace: \n
```